# sencha touch 2 html5 canvas drawimage blu image resolution

Tags: html, canvas, sencha-touch-2

I have a problem when I use `drawImage` function to draw an image inside an html5 canvas ;used with a code Sencha Touch 2 images look blu and they don't have height quality this is the code:

```
    //We've added a third and final item to our tab panel - scroll down to see it
var index=0;
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',
    launch: function() {
        var panel = Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
            fullscreen: true,

            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    cls: 'home',                            

                    width: '533px',
                    listeners: {
                    painted: function() {

                    var a={Source:'images/2.tiff',Titre:'T1',Description:'D1'};
                    var b={Source:'images/Im2.jpg',Titre:'T1',Description:'D1'};
                    var c={Source:'images/Im3.jpg',Titre:'T1',Description:'D1'};
                    var d={Source:'images/Im4.jpg',Titre:'T1',Description:'D1'};
                    var e={Source:'images/Im5.jpg',Titre:'T1',Description:'D1'};
                    var f={Source:'images/Im6.jpg',Titre:'T1',Description:'D1'};

                    var img = new Image();
                    var img1 = new Image();
                    var img2 = new Image();


                    img.src = "images/Im1.jpg";
                    img1.src = "images/Im2.jpg";
                    img2.src = "images/Im3.jpg";
                    var ImageP = new Image();  
                    //********************
                    var x,y,Dim_Image,espacement;
                    Dim_Image=50;
                    espacement=30;

                    var Presentation=new Array();
                        Presentation[0]=a;
                        Presentation[1]=b;
                        Presentation[2]=c;
                        Presentation[3]=d;
                        Presentation[4]=e;
                        Presentation[5]=f;
                    //********************

                    //°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
                    /* Ici on teste le tableau*/
                    var testImage = new Array();
                    //cw-(i*espacement),i*espacement,Dim_Image,Dim_Image);
                    var j=0;
                    for(i=index;i<index+3;i++)
                    {

                        testImage[i]= new Image();
                        testImage[i].src=Presentation[i].Source;        
                        testImage[i].onload  = function()
                        {
                        context.drawImage(testImage[j],cw-80-(j*espacement),20+j*espacement,Dim_Image,Dim_Image);
                        j++;
                        }

                    }index = index +1;

                    var img = new Image();
                    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas'); 
                        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        var cw = canvas.width;
                        var ch = canvas.height;
                        //Event================================================================
                        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown" ,function(event){

                        testImage = new Array();
                        context.clearRect(0,0,300,300); // clear canvas  
                        var j=0;var inf =index;var ss;
                        for(i=index;i<index+3;i++)
                        {

                            testImage[i-index]= new Image();

                            testImage[i-index].src=Presentation[i].Source;  
                            if( i == index+2)
                            {alert("index +3");
                            testImage[i-index].onload  = function()
                            {context.globalAlpha=1; 
                            context.drawImage(testImage[j],cw-80-(j*espacement),20+j*espacement,Dim_Image,Dim_Image);

                            j++;
                            }
                           }
                           else{
                            testImage[i-index].onload  = function()
                            {context.globalAlpha=0.5; 
                            context.drawImage(testImage[j],cw-80-(j*espacement),20+j*espacement,Dim_Image,Dim_Image);

                            j++;
                            }
                           }

                        }
                        index=index+1;
                        context.stroke();
                        },false);

                        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
                        context.stroke();
                    //};
                    },
                    scope: this
                    },
                    html: [
                      ' <canvas id="mycanvas" style="background-color:grey; width:100%; height:100%;">no canvas support</canvas>'
                    ]
                }            //this is the new item
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Perhaps the problem is related to the drawImage method type you are using

Have a look at this link on the usage how to use, and what exactly the parameters that you added means.

Problem may be aspect ratio , width , height calculation from your side.
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage